# Reading GUI Object Data in Worker Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface, concurrency

I just read the lesson on [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) in the Java tutorials. It pretty much deals exclusively with returning interim and final results from methods running on worker threads back to methods running on the dispatch thread. I was wondering about data flow in the other direction. Are methods running on worker threads free to read variables belonging to GUI objects and invoke their data-returning methods as long as they don't change any of the object's data?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you have in mind? What is the requirement that is driving this question? Something that polls the GUI? That seems a strange requirement if so.

Comment: You would have a background thread reading state that the EDT is updating. Without proper synchronization, that won't work correctly.

Comment: How about reading the entered value from a JTextField or reading the state of a JCheckBox and using those results to influence the method executing on the worker thread?

Comment: @Greg Valvo: How about passing the text from the JTextField or the state of a JCheckBox to the worker thread before you start it?  That's what model classes are for using the [model / view / controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How about reading the entered value from a JTextField or reading the state of a JCheckBox and using those results to influence the method executing on the worker thread?

Easy: The state of the JTextField and the JCheckBox would be read on the Swing event thread, the information then would likely be passed into the Worker via its constructor (again on the Swing event thread), and then the work executed off of the event thread.

---

> OK, I'm thinking about a fairly large amount of data. So, the call to the constructor would be kind of awkward / ugly passing all those parameters.

Then create a separate class to hold the parameter data, or use collections, or both. This is not Swing or SwingWorker specific but the same solution for the issue of passing a large amount of data to any method or object.

> Maybe have the constructor itself pull the data from the GUI elements and store in variables for the worker thread?

I vote against this as it increases your code's coupling and reduces cohesion. The worker should be as ignorant as possible of the GUI and should just concentrate on being given its data and then doing its work. For this reason I try to use PropertyChangeListeners with my workers as much as possible.

Comment: OK, I'm thinking about a fairly large amount of data. So, the call to the constructor would be kind of awkward / ugly passing all those parameters. Maybe have the constructor itself pull the data from the GUI elements and store in variables for the worker thread?